# Trying to backward through the graph a second time in Physics Informed Neural Network (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, derivative

I am trying to train a Physics Informed Neural Network which has two outputs from Two Different PDEs.

The First PDE is the 2D Heat Equation while the second PDE is the 2D Oxygen diffusion in a 2D domain.

I splitted the loss functions into two functions one for the Heat equation (First PDE) and one for the second PDE.

I didn't combine the two losses together to reduce the error and to ensure stability. In addition, the Boundary conditions and initial Conditions for each PDE are different.

I created two training loop.

The part of the code that contains the PINN is in the following:

```
class FCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers):
        super(FCN, self).__init__()
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i + 1]) for i in range(len(layers) - 1)])
        for i in range(len(layers) - 1):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linears[i].weight.data, gain=1)
            nn.init.zeros_(self.linears[i].bias.data)

    def forward(self, x):
        if not torch.is_tensor(x):
            x = torch.from_numpy(x)
        x = x.float()
        # Assuming ub and lb are defined elsewhere in your code
        u_b = ub.float().to(device)
        l_b = lb.float().to(device)
        x = (x - l_b) / (u_b - l_b)  # feature scaling
        a = x
        for i in range(len(self.linears) - 1):
            z = self.linears[i](a)
            a = self.activation(z)
        a = self.linears[-1](a)
        return a

    def loss_T(self, x_BC_T, y_BC_T, x_PDE, alpha):
        # Boundary condition loss for T
        output_BC_T = self.forward(x_BC_T)
        loss_BC_T = self.loss_function(output_BC_T, y_BC_T)
    
        g = x_PDE.clone()
        g.requires_grad = True
    
        output = self.forward(g)  # This outputs both T and Pb, shape [n_samples, 2]
        self.Temp = output[:, 0:1]  # Splitting Temp
    
        # Gradient of T with respect to input
        T_grad = autograd.grad(self.Temp, g, torch.ones([g.shape[0], 1]).to(device), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
        # Laplacian of T
        T_grad2 = autograd.grad(T_grad, g, torch.ones(g.shape).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
    
        T_t = T_grad[:, [2]]  # Assuming the 3rd column of g corresponds to time
        T_xx = T_grad2[:, [0]]  # Assuming the 1st column of g corresponds to x
        T_yy = T_grad2[:, [1]]  # Assuming the 2nd column of g corresponds to y
    
        # Heat equation for T
        T_res = T_t - alpha * (T_xx + T_yy)
        loss_pde_T = self.loss_function(T_res, torch.zeros(T_t.shape).to(device))
    
        # L2 regularization
        l2_reg = torch.tensor(0.).to(device)
        for param in self.parameters():
            l2_reg += torch.norm(param) ** 2
    
        # Total loss
        total_loss_T = loss_BC_T  + loss_pde_T 
        
        return total_loss_T

    def loss_Pb(self, x_BC_Pb, y_BC_Pb, x_PDE, fcf, D_0, c_0, R, h, dCA_dt):
        # Boundary condition loss for Pb
        output_BC_Pb = self.forward(x_BC_Pb)
        loss_BC_Pb = self.loss_function(output_BC_Pb, y_BC_Pb)
    
    
        g = x_PDE.clone()
        g.requires_grad = True
    
        output = self.forward(g)  # This outputs both T and Pb, shape [n_samples, 2]
        Pb = output[:, 1:2]  # Splitting Pb
    
        # Gradient of Pb with respect to input
        Pb_grad = autograd.grad(Pb, g, torch.ones([g.shape[0], 1]).to(device), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
        # Laplacian of Pb
        Pb_grad2 = autograd.grad(Pb_grad, g, torch.ones(g.shape).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
    
        Pb_t = Pb_grad[:, [2]]
        Pb_xx = Pb_grad2[:, [0]]
        Pb_yy = Pb_grad2[:, [1]]
        # PDE for Pb, incorporating T
        Pb_res = Pb_t - fcf * D_0 * (Pb_xx + Pb_yy) + (c_0 * self.Temp * R / h) * dCA_dt
        loss_pde_Pb = self.loss_function(Pb_res, torch.zeros(Pb_t.shape).to(device))
    
        # L2 regularization
        l2_reg = torch.tensor(0.).to(device)
        for param in self.parameters():
            l2_reg += torch.norm(param) ** 2
    
        # Total loss
        total_loss_Pb = loss_BC_Pb  + loss_pde_Pb 
    
        return total_loss_Pb


# Initialize the model, optimizer, etc.
layers = np.array([3, 256, 2]) # Two Outputs T and Pb 
PINN = FCN(layers)
PINN.to(device)

# Using LBFGS as the optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(PINN.parameters(), lr=1, max_iter=20, tolerance_grad=1e-7, tolerance_change=1e-9, history_size=100)

fcf = 1
D_0 = 1E-11
c_0 = 0.00367
R = 8.67
h = 0.0076
dCA_dt  = 1

# Training loop without curriculum learning
epochs = 1
alpha = 0.1  # Fixed alpha value
loss_history = []

x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)  # Adjust as needed
y_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)  # Adjust as needed
t_value = 0.5  # Fixed time for visualization, adjust as needed

X_mesh, Y_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
T_mesh = np.full_like(X_mesh, t_value)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Resample collocation points for each epoch T
    idx = np.random.choice(T_X_train.shape[0], Nu, replace=False)
    X_train_Nu = T_X_train[idx, :]
    Y_train_Nu = T_Y_train[idx, :]

    # Resample using MCMC for each epoch Pb
    X_train_Nf = torch.zeros((Nf, 3)).to(device)
    X_train_Nf[0, :] = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]).to(device)
    for i in range(1, Nf):
        X_train_Nf[i, :] = X_train_Nf[i - 1, :] + 0.1 * torch.randn(3).to(device)
        if torch.any(X_train_Nf[i, :] < lb) or torch.any(X_train_Nf[i, :] > ub):
            X_train_Nf[i, :] = X_train_Nf[i - 1, :]
 
    # Normalize the newly sampled points
    X_train_Nu_normalized = (X_train_Nu - lb) / (ub - lb)
    X_train_Nf_normalized = (X_train_Nf - lb) / (ub - lb)
    X_train_Nu_normalized = X_train_Nu_normalized.float().to(device)
    Y_train_Nu = Y_train_Nu.float().to(device)
    X_train_Nf_normalized = X_train_Nf_normalized.float().to(device)

    def closure_T():
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_value_T = PINN.loss_T(X_train_Nu_normalized, Y_train_Nu, X_train_Nf_normalized, alpha)
        loss_value_T.backward(retain_graph= True)
        return loss_value_T

    # Optimize for T
    optimizer.step(closure_T)
    
    # Optional: Log or print the loss for T
    loss_value_T = closure_T()  # Note: This will re-compute the loss; remove if efficiency is a concern
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1}, Loss T: {loss_value_T.item()}")
    
    # Plotting after each epoch
    plot_heat_distribution(PINN, X_mesh, Y_mesh, t_value, device)
    
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Resample collocation points for each epoch
    idx2 = np.random.choice(Pb_X_train.shape[0], Nu2, replace=False)
    X_train_Nu2 = Pb_X_train[idx2, :]
    Y_train_Nu2 = Pb_Y_train[idx2, :]

    # Resample using MCMC for each epoch
    X_train_Nf2 = torch.zeros((Nf2, 3)).to(device)
    X_train_Nf2[0, :] = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]).to(device)
    for i in range(1, Nf2):
        X_train_Nf2[i, :] = X_train_Nf2[i - 1, :] + 0.1 * torch.randn(3).to(device)
        if torch.any(X_train_Nf2[i, :] < lb) or torch.any(X_train_Nf2[i, :] > ub):
            X_train_Nf2[i, :] = X_train_Nf2[i - 1, :]
            
            
    X_train_Nu2_normalized = (X_train_Nu2 - lb) / (ub - lb)
    X_train_Nf2_normalized = (X_train_Nf2 - lb) / (ub - lb)
    X_train_Nu2_normalized = X_train_Nu2_normalized.float().to(device)
    Y_train_Nu2 = Y_train_Nu2.float().to(device)
    X_train_Nf2_normalized = X_train_Nf2_normalized.float().to(device)
    
    
    # Closure for loss Pb
    def closure_Pb():
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients
        loss_value_Pb = PINN.loss_Pb(X_train_Nu2_normalized, Y_train_Nu2, X_train_Nf2_normalized, fcf, D_0, c_0, R, h, dCA_dt)
        loss_value_Pb.backward()  # Compute gradients for loss Pb
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1}, Loss Pb: {loss_value_Pb.item()}")  # Print here
        return loss_value_Pb
    
    optimizer.step(closure_Pb)

    # Plotting after each epoch
    plot_dependent_variable(PINN, X_mesh, Y_mesh, t_value, device)
```

however, the model worked perfectly well for the first loop and I got the following error before starting the second loop:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

def closure_Pb():
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients
    loss_value_Pb = PINN.loss_Pb(X_train_Nu2_normalized, Y_train_Nu2, X_train_Nf2_normalized, fcf, D_0, c_0, R, h, dCA_dt)
    loss_value_Pb.backward()  # Compute gradients for loss Pb
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1}, Loss Pb: {loss_value_Pb.item()}")  # Print here
    return loss_value_Pb

optimizer.step(closure_Pb)
```

it seems that it is not allowed to call `.backward()` two times I assigned the added the following `retain_graph = True` but still the same problem!

Any help!

Note: I designed my code in way to resample the collection points for each training epoch

Comment: You shouldn't need to call backward twice. If you take your first model and feed it through your second model then feed that to the loss, like `result = loss(2nd(1st(x)))`, then call `result.backward()` that should work. But you say that you didn't combine the losses from each network, that could be why you're experiencing that.